# Show that $f(x) = \int_{1}^{\ln{x}} \frac{t^{3}}{e^{t} -1} dt$ is an increasing function.

Tags: calculus

**Problem:**

Show that:

$$f(x) = \int_{1}^{\ln{x}} \frac{t^{3}}{e^{t} -1} dt,  ~~~~~~~x \ > 1,$$

is an increasing function.

**Attempted answer:**

My basic strategy here is to rely on the fundamental theorem of calculus and then the chain rule to show that the derivative of $f(x)$ is positive for the $x$ values listed, which I think is enough to show that the original function is an increasing function.

The reason for this is that I have seen similar examples that uses this technique, so it is a reasonable first attempt.

Let us define:

$$S(u) = \int_{1}^{u} \frac{t^{3}}{e^{t} -1} dt,  ~~~~~~u = \ln{x}$$

Now, applying the chain rule, we get:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{dS}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{e^x -1} \cdot \frac{1}{x}  = \frac{x^2}{e^x-1}$$

This is has a positive value for $x > 1$, so the original function must be an increasing function  for $x > 1$.

I have no expected answer (except that it is probably an increasing function) and Wolfram Alpha tells me there is too little computational resources to calculate it. So I am mathematizing somewhat in the dark and unsure of if and when I am "done".

Is this a correct approach? If yes, is there something that is missing? If no, what are some productive approaches to test instead?

Comment: This is more than likely the intended solution.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. I can offer another one based on showing the integrand is positive for all values in the range.

If $x>e$, the upper bound of the integral is larger than 1. It is easy to show that $\frac{t^3}{e^t-1}>0$ for all $t$. If $x<e$, we swap the bounds, which changes the sign of the function and the integrand $\frac{t^3}{1-e^t}>0$ for all $t$.

Comment: $\frac{dS}{du}=\frac{u^3}{e^u-1}=\frac{(\ln x)^3}{x-1}$